# Dynamic Label Break line

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, uilabel, line-breaks

I have created a form using vb net which extracts data from a database, some of which is displayed tot the user via labels which are dynamically created. However, i need to be able to make the label 'break a line' after - say n letters. I havent been able to find a way to do this, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just add a line break after n characters, you can use something like:

```
Dim myStr As String = "Hello123"
Label1.Text = myStr.Substring(0, 5) & vbNewLine & myStr.Substring(5)
```

**Output:**

```
Hello
123
```

Hope this helps